# Azure Keyvault to access resources from different azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use `azure keyvault` in my MVC application to get storage account keys. This MVC application is hosted in different azure subscriptions with storage accounts belonging to those subscriptions. Is it possible to have a one `Azure Keyvault` resource in any subscription and serve keys for storage accounts residing in different subscriptions?

Comment: Are those subscriptions linked to the same Azure AD tenant?

Comment: Not at the moment. Few of those subscriptions share common AD Tenant. But few other share different AD tenent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

You will need to make identities for the apps using the Key Vault in the Azure AD tenant where the Key Vault's subscription is. And then assign permissions to access the vault to those service principals.

Then you can put the client id, client secret and tenant id to the apps that need to access the Key Vault. They should then be able to call it, since they have an identity that is allowed access. Key Vault uses an HTTP API so whether the apps and the vault are in the same subscription/data center/cloud provider is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Juunas..   Should the KeyVault be in the Azure AD Tenant to make it work ?

Comment: Well, the vault *will be* in some Azure AD tenant for sure. The important thing is that you create the application identities in the same tenant, so that you can assign permissions to them to access the vault.

Comment: So if you create your vault in subscription A, and that subscription is linked to tenant ABC, then you must create the app identities in tenant ABC.

Comment: have you tried it? it is not necessary possible, like you cant deploy webapp certificates across subscriptions with kv, for instance.

Comment: Well that could be true :) But if it is just about storage connection strings in secrets, there isn't really a reason it would not work.

Comment: Old thread, but I spent many hours trying to create an identify of a web app in subscription A, access a KeyVault in subscription B, and could not get it to work... moved to web app to subscription B, and immediately started to work - some 6 hours of testing.... argh

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use below to do via azure CLI

```
 az webapp config ssl import -n 'webappname' -g 'webappresourcegroup' --key-vault "/subscriptions/[provide subscriptionID]/resourceGroups/[Provide resource group Name]/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[Provide Vault Name] --key-vault-certificate 'Provide certificate Name'
```